# Editing Task Scheduler Tasks C#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I am using the Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper to create Scheduled tasks from an external program(SharePoint) Creating and reading the tasks is fine but I cannot find a way to edit the task once it has been registered, do I have to re-register a new task or perform an update request somehow?

**Register my Task:**

```
TaskDefinition newTask = taskService.NewTask();
newTask.RegistrationInfo.Description = (string)timerJobItem.FieldValues["Description"];
newTask.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken;

// Switch for different schedule options, use createTriggers method
List<Trigger> triggers = createTriggers((string)timerJobItem["Schedule"], (DateTime)timerJobItem["StartTime"]);
newTask.Triggers.Add(triggers.First());

// Create Action to add to new Task
newTask.Actions.Add(new ExecAction((string)timerJobItem["Action"], (string)timerJobItem["Arguments"], null));
// Create Task
taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(jobName, newTask);
```

Then I find the task in the scheduler which works, but when I try to make changes nothing happens:

```
// Method to get all Tasks that match a name - Working
private Task[] GetAllTasks(string regexString)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(String.Format(@"{0}", regexString));
        using (TaskService taskService = new TaskService())
        {
            Task[] allTasksCollection = taskService.FindAllTasks(regex, true);
            foreach (Task task in allTasksCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(task.Name);
            }
            return allTasksCollection;
        };
    }
```

**....**

```
// Get a single timer job
Task[] allTimerJobs = GetAllTasks(prefix);
List<Task> allTimerJobsList = allTimerJobs.Cast<Task>().ToList();
string jobName = String.Format("{0}[{1}].{2}", prefix, (int)timerJobItem["ID"], jobReference);

// Get Task by name
int indexOfJob = allTimerJobsList.FindIndex(t => t.Name == jobName);
Task matchingJob = allTimerJobsList[indexOfJob];

// No Error but nothing happens to task
matchingJob.Definition.Triggers.Clear();

// No Error but nothing happens to task
matchingJob.Definition.Settings.Enabled = false;
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to edit the task is to copy the Definition to a new task and register it in the RootFolder again.

The below example, changes the description to the new value, the task name must match or a new task will be created:

```
TaskDefinition td = taskService.NewTask();
td = existingJob.Definition;
td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "New Value";
taskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(jobName, td);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 3 years ago, but have you tried:

```
td.RegisterChanges();
```

Comment: haha, no idea this was a blast from the past, can't even remember what I was doing it for

Answer (score 0):

To modify result you have found by GetAllTasks method, you should declare using statement out of function and send it as parameter.

```
private Task[] GetAllTasks(TaskService taskService, string regexString)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(String.Format(@"{0}", regexString));

    Task[] allTasksCollection = taskService.FindAllTasks(regex, true);
        foreach (Task task in allTasksCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Name);
        }
        return allTasksCollection;

}
```

to use that method declare using statement in your modify method

```
// Get a single timer job
using (TaskService taskService = new TaskService())
{
    Task[] allTimerJobs = GetAllTasks(taskService, prefix);
    List<Task> allTimerJobsList = allTimerJobs.Cast<Task>().ToList();
    string jobName = String.Format("{0}[{1}].{2}", prefix, (int)timerJobItem["ID"],jobReference);
    // Get Task by name
    int indexOfJob = allTimerJobsList.FindIndex(t => t.Name == jobName);
    Task matchingJob = allTimerJobsList[indexOfJob];
    // No Error but nothing happens to task
    matchingJob.Definition.Triggers.Clear();
    // No Error but nothing happens to task
    matchingJob.Definition.Settings.Enabled = false;
}
```